# How to know if a connection error occurred when using thrift from a javascript client?

Tags: javascript, thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm running the following thrift javascript client code. If the server is down, I don't get any error in the callback - just console log message.

**How do I know if there're connection issues if the callback isn't invoked?**

Javascript thrift client code:

```
var transport = new Thrift.Transport("/api/thrift/");
var protocol = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);
var client = new ApiClient(protocol);
client.doSomething(function (result) {
  // Never invoked if the server is down.
});
```

Console log message:

```
POST http://localhost:81/api/thrift/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Usually I get answers faster than 2 days. Doesn't bode well for Apache Thrift. At least there are +3 google plus votes.

Comment: Almost a year back and still not answer? Strange.

Comment: in C++ there are Exceptions thrown if doSomething didn't find its way to the server. Not sure how it works in Java...

Comment: @Micka The question is abount javascript.

Comment: I know, that's why I've written the C++ state. I have no idea whether javascript has some kind of exception handling, but if it has that might be the thing to try here ;)

Comment: this code sample uses exception handling around the client call: https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/js